# cin chars and insert them into a 2d array

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, cin

I would like to read from a file using cin and redirection and place them into a 2d array. Unfortunately, I keep getting a segfault because of the blank spaces after the input file, (I've checked and there are no blank spaces after the last character. Here's what I have.

input.txt

```
abcd
efgh
ijkl
mnop
```

Here's a snippet of my code:

```
char c; 
int i =0; int j=0;

while(cin >> c){
    ary[i][j] = c; 
    ++i; 
    ++j;
    }
```

The goal is to have a matrix like this:

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
['e', 'f', 'g', 'h']
['i', 'j', 'k', 'l']
['m', 'n', 'o', 'p']
```

Is there a way to tell cin to ignore all blank spaces or newlines after the letter p? I tried cin.get(c) and that doesn't seem to do the trick. Here's how I'm running my script: ./executable < input.txt

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you think the segfault is due to blank spaces or new lines? Your loop is all wrong.

Comment: it's not because of the blank spaces. it's because you are incrementing both `i` and `j` inside the loop at the same time, hence you are indexing the array out of bounds. You should have an inner and an outer loop or maybe just one induction variable altogether (and division and modulo to compute the indices of the two dimensions).

Comment: What they said. You'll need a double for loop: one for each row, and one for each column of that row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run the script in your head. See what output it provides. You will clearly see you can never reference ary[0][1], ary[0][2], etc.

Did you try using debugger? It's a really useful tool.

Anyway; you need to do something different - I suggest you using `for` loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
{
   for(int j = 0; j < 4; ++j)
   {
       std::cin >> tab[i][j];
   }
}
```

Usually if you're operating on tabs or input with fixed size(like yours), you want to use for loop - easier to manage

Comment: not sure how to word this question but, cin can remember its place in the file? That's what was throwing me off. I thought most file reads needed a while loop.

Comment: You may say that `cin` kind of consumes input - so if you have "|abc" and use cin, you get "|bc" <- and a now resides in your memory(or is just forgotten).

People usually use `while` loop for reading various files, because they don't know the length of the file - so you usually do something like `while(std::getline(str, cin));`(the function might be wrong, writing from memory), and loop will terminate after reaching end of file. You just need to be aware of what you're consuming(what type of data). Rest is done by `cin`. However, in your example with fixed size, for loop is okay(and easier).